# Kubernetes Secret is persisting through deletes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I'm trying to clean up some leftover data from a failed deployment of rabbitmq.  As such, I have 3 secrets that were being used by rabbit services that never fully started.  Whenever I try to delete these using kubectl delete secret  they get recreated with a similar name instantly (even when using --force).

I do not see any services or pods that are using these secrets, so there shouldn't be any reason they are persisting.

Example of what happens when I delete:
[image]

Comment: What is the message you get when you sun kubectl delete secret...

Comment: secret "name" deleted

Comment: delete the secret and check the event logs, "kubectl get events"

Comment: no resources found

Comment: What happens when you delete all deployment in the current namespace?

Comment: @RaunakJhawar can't do that as it will break oh so many things.

Comment: Ok what happens when you delete the pods associated with these secrets? Have you deployed any of them via deployment? Do they get created again?

Comment: there are currently no pods assocated with these secrets.  Nothing I can find is associated with these secrets.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The reason they wouldn't delete is because they were associated with a service account.

I found this by looking at their yaml files, which mentioned they were for a service account.

I then ran

```
kubectl get serviceaccounts
```

which returned a list of accounts that had identical names.  After running

```
kubectl delete serviceaccounts <accountName>
```

The secrets removed themselves.

However, if they do not, you can still get and delete them with

```
kubectl get secrets
kubectl delete secret <secret name>
```

If you do not see the item in question, you may want to append --all-namespaces to see "all" of them, as by default it looks at the top level of your kubernetes environment.

Comment: It would be helpful to update your answer to show the correct arguments that the newer versions of `kubectl` works with.  I was almost going to add an answer but seems unnecessary with your answer simply needing to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was simpler - the secret was created within a namespace i.e. with

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry <secret> --namespace <namespace>
```

in order to delete such a secret you need to append the namespace name to the `kubectl delete secret` command:

```
kubectl delete secret <secret-name> -n <namespace-name>
```